# Not Able to parse JSON response which is holding url

Tags: android, json

I am trying to parse JSON response where i am able to parse title,date, content and name but iam not able to parse url and display it in Listview. when i parse the url it is displaying image url in textview  Can anybody direct me in right path

```
 try {
                     posts = json.getJSONArray(KEY_POSTS);

        // looping through all song nodes <song>
                for(int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = posts.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(KEY_ID);
                    String siteurl = c.getString(KEY_SITEURL);
                    String title = c.getString(KEY_TITLE);
                    String date = c.getString(KEY_DATE);
                    String content = c.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
                    // to remove all <P> </p> and <br /> and replace with ""
                     content = content.replace("<br />", "");
                     content = content.replace("<p>", "");
                     content = content.replace("</p>", "");

                    //authornumber is agin  JSON Object
                    JSONObject author = c.getJSONObject(KEY_AUTHOR);
                    String name = author.getString(KEY_NAME);

                    String url1 = null;
                    String slug1 = null;
                    try {
                    JSONArray atta = c.getJSONArray("attachments");
                    for(int j = 0; j < atta.length(); j++){
                        JSONObject d = atta.getJSONObject(j);

                        slug1 = d.getString(KEY_SLUG);

                        JSONObject images = d.getJSONObject(KEY_IMAGES);

                        JSONObject thumbnail = images.getJSONObject(KEY_THUMB_URL);
                        url1 = thumbnail.getString(KEY_URL);

                    }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }




            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, id);
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
            map.put(KEY_SITEURL, siteurl);
            map.put(KEY_DATE, date);
            map.put(KEY_NAME, name);
            map.put(KEY_CONTENT, content);
            map.put(KEY_SLUG, slug1);
            map.put(KEY_URL, url1);


            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
                }   
                }catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    }
```

Comment: The JSON example you have posted does not have the **key *siteurl***. In fact the only URL's I see are **key *url***

Comment: yes only url only but in code i have given KEY_SITEURL and KEY_URL to make diffrence between both url's @SiddharthLele

Comment: Yes. And that is a good thing to do. But which key element from the JSON is the URL for the _link_ and which key element is for the _image url_?

Comment: In the above JSON example let me take title="Commander Retreat for sale" for this the link url is  "url": "http://india.dollardesi.net/ads/commander-retreat-for-sale/" (11th line in json) and image url is in attachments-> images->thumbnail-> url. In next "title": "Prestige Shantiniketan for sale" but attachments:[]= which contains image url is empty, but it contains link url("id": 2966 ) @SiddharthLele

Comment: Then just check if the _attachment_ contains data. If it doesn't, you still have the URL (the one after the **id**) to display in your `TextView`. I am sorry, but I still don't see where the problem really is. It is just a matter of checking if data exists and grabbing it or not grabbing it.